Issues with camera: very slow setup, and first attempt never works
In this example I want to take a picture and calculate the average green pixel value in the image. The app works, but I have the following issues:

When first running the app on my phone from Xcode, it takes a lot of time for the button to become responsive (about 10 s). This however doesn't happen again after force quitting and relaunching the app.
When the button is responsive, the first attempt at taking a picture never works (regardless of the time I wait for the app to load before attempting), and I get this message in the console:
<<<< AVCapturePhotoOutput >>>> Fig assert: "hasFigCaptureSession" at bail (AVCapturePhotoOutput.m:508) - (err=0)
This happens every time, even after force quitting and relaunching.
The shutter noise increases in volume after each time I take a picture, and converges after a few times to a certain (high) level.

Would anyone have suggestions to solve those three issues? (main one being the second)
My code:
import SwiftUI
import AVFoundation

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var averageGreen: Double = 0.0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Average Green Value: \(averageGreen, specifier: "%.2f")")
                .padding()

            Button(action: {
                CameraController.shared.capturePhoto { photoData in
                    if let photoData = photoData {
                        if let uiImage = UIImage(data: photoData) {
                            self.averageGreen = calculateAverageGreenValue(image: uiImage)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }) {
                Text("Take Photo")
                    .padding()
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .cornerRadius(8)
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

func calculateAverageGreenValue(image: UIImage) -> Double {
    guard let cgImage = image.cgImage else { return 0.0 }
    guard let data = cgImage.dataProvider?.data else { return 0.0 }
    guard let ptr = CFDataGetBytePtr(data) else { return 0.0 }

    let width = cgImage.width
    let height = cgImage.height
    let bytesPerPixel = 4

    var totalGreen = 0

    for y in 0..<height {
        for x in 0..<width {
            let pixelIndex = ((width * y) + x) * bytesPerPixel
            let g = Int(ptr[pixelIndex + 1]) // Green component

            totalGreen += g
        }
    }

    return Double(totalGreen) / Double(width * height)
}


class CameraController: NSObject, AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate {
    static let shared = CameraController()

    private var captureSession: AVCaptureSession?
    private var photoOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput?
    private var completionHandler: ((Data?) -> Void)?

    override init() {
        super.init()
        setupSession()
    }

    private func setupSession() {
        captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
        captureSession?.sessionPreset = .low  // low resolution

        guard let backCamera = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video),
              let input = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: backCamera) else { return }

        if captureSession?.canAddInput(input) ?? false {
            captureSession?.addInput(input)
        }

        photoOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
        if captureSession?.canAddOutput(photoOutput!) ?? false {
            captureSession?.addOutput(photoOutput!)
        }

        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async { [weak self] in
            self?.captureSession?.startRunning()
        }
    }

    func capturePhoto(completion: @escaping (Data?) -> Void) {
        self.completionHandler = completion
        let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
        settings.flashMode = .off  // Disable the flash
        photoOutput?.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: self)
    }

    func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {
        guard let imageData = photo.fileDataRepresentation() else {
            completionHandler?(nil)
            return
        }
        completionHandler?(imageData)
    }
}


my assumption is you are Initiated capture session on  global queue so when you will get output put it should be on main thread and  do the same with capturePhoto func which create a completion.

I have few suggestions for optimizing.

Initialize av session onAppear method on ContentView
 CameraController.shared.initializeSession()


In initalizeSession check if session not running already


if captureSession == nil {
    setupSession()
}


Move

func capturePhoto(completion: @escaping (Data?) -> Void) {
    self.completionHandler = completion
    let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
    settings.flashMode = .off  // Disable the flash
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async { [weak self] in
        photoOutput?.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: self)
    }
}



Thanks a lot. I only have basic knowledge of Swift so just to make sure: did you mean to add .onAppear {CameraController.shared.initializeSession()} to my "take photo" button, and define below an initializeSession() function containing your code in point 2?
When I replace my capturePhoto function by yours I have this error message on the last line: Value of optional type 'CameraController?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'CameraController'
